# Limit of $\tan(\pi x/2)$ as $x$ tends to $1^-$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

Find the limit of the following :

$$\lim_{x \to 1^{-}}\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right).$$

I'm confused about the value of it..whether it is infinite or it does not exist.

Please clarify anyone my doubt.

**Edit:** My actual problem was to check whether the function $\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)$ in uniform continuous (or not) in $(0,1)$.

Comment: the searched limit is $$+\infty$$

Comment: Folks have addressed your original, implicit question, "whether it is infinite or it does not exist."  You shouldn't add another question to an already posted question, after you've already received answers to your original question.

Answer (score 2):

I think most people would say that limits that go to infinity do not exist.  But it's a special case of non-existence.  Some limit's don't exist because the function bounces around too much.  But this limit doesn't exist because it increases without bound.

Some folks will say "What about the extended reals?" which contains $\pm \infty.$
In this case, it would be fair to say the limit exists, but that's not going to be the most common usage.

Response to edit:  In that case you don't need to know this limit.  $1$ is not i your domain.  The fact that the derivative is unbounded (in the open interval) is sufficient to show that the function is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: Downvotes ? why ?????

Comment: How you say that unbounded derivative give non-uniform continuity ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \to 1^{-}}\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-}\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}.$$

Now, $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \sin x=1.$ But when $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-},\;~\cos x$ approaches to zero through positive values. Hence the limit you're looking for is $+\infty.$

Or convince yourself with the following graph.

[image: Or convince yourself with the graph.]

Comment: I believe the first line, second part, should have $x \to \pi$ instead of $x \to \pi /2$, or, looking at the following part, tan should have instead just $x$ as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

$x\rightarrow 1^{-}$, $x\pi/2\rightarrow \pi/2^{-}$,

$sin(x\pi/2)\rightarrow 1$, $cos(x\pi/2)\rightarrow 0^+$ so the limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: in Germany we say that is an improper limit